# Testing method inside functional component in React using Jest / Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

Following is my React Functional Component which I am trying to test using `jest` / `enzyme`.

React Functional Component Code -

```
export const UserForm = props => {
    const {labels, formFields, errorMessages} = props;
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);
    const [newId, setNewId] = React.useState('');

    const showModal = () => {
        setShowModal(true);
    }

    const closeModal = () => {
        setShowModal(false);
    };

    const handleSubmit = data => {
        Post(url, data)
            .then(resp => {
                const userData = resp.data;
                setNewId(() => userData.id);
                showModal();
            })
    }

    return (
        <div className="user-form">
            <UserForm
                fields={formFields}
                handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
                labels={labels}
                errors={errorMessages}
            />
            {showModal && <Modal closeModal={closeModal}>
                <div className="">
                    <h3>Your new id is - {newId}</h3>
                    <Button
                        type="button"
                        buttonLabel="Close"
                        handleClick={closeModal}
                        classes="btn btn-close"
                    />
                </div>
            </Modal>}
        </div>
    )
};
```

Now I am trying to test `showModal`, `closeModal` and `handleSubmit` method, but my tests are failing. Let me know the correct way of testing React Hooks and methods inside functional component.

My test case -

```
import React from 'react';
import { UserForm } from '../index';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('<UserForm />', () => {
    let wrapper;
    const labels = {
        success: 'Success Message'
    };
    const formFields = [];
    const errorMessages = {
        labels: {
            firstName: 'First Name Missing'
        }
    };

    function renderShallow() {
        wrapper = shallow(<UserForm
            labels={labels}
            formFields={formFields}
            errorMessages={errorMessages}
        />);
    }
    it('should render with props(snapshot)', () => {
        renderShallow();
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('should test showModal method', () => {
        const mockSetShowModal = jest.fn();
        React.useState = jest.fn(() => [false, mockSetShowModal]);

        renderShallow();
        expect(mockSetShowModal).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
    });
});
```

Error I am getting -

```
Expected mock function to have been called with:
      [true]
    But it was not called.
```

Let me know how can i test the `showModal`, `closeModal` and `handleSubmit` methods in a functional component.

Comment: Shouldn't you just add the call of the mock function `mockSetShowModal(true)` just before the `expect(mockSetShowModal)...` line?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, functional components in React aren't meant to be tested in that way. The React team are suggesting that you use the approach of React Testing Library which is more focused on the actual user interface scenarios. Instead of testing React component instances, you're testing DOM nodes.

This is the main reason why people are moving away from Enzyme and starting to use RTL, because you want to avoid testing implementation details as much as you can.

Comment: Then can you please give an example to unit test functional component which contains several methods using RTL ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I now realize that I was wrong with testing methods in isolation. No, you cannot test functions inside a functional component, and you are not supposed to either.

Comment: To clarify further: you are supposed to test the behavior of the component, not the functions.

Comment: ok. But in future, mostly Reactjs app will be written in functional components then how we can achieve 100% code coverage using npm test if we are not allowed to test functions inside functional components in RTL.

Comment: The purpose of testing a React component is not to achieve a complete code coverage, but to cover the potential test cases of the component. I encourage you to read more about the philosophy behind React Testing Library: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/

Comment: I know the purpose of testing react components but is there any way to test such methods, vars etc. which are in functional components?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Ok then we should avoid RTL and use cypress or jest. Because if there is scenario at DevOps pipeline to coverage more than 80% then it's not achievable using RTL only